# Learning about plants

Tags: identification

This site provides a valuable service of plant identification, but I'm wondering, where can I learn this for myself? Is there a plant "dictionary" I can check out from the library? One that will allow me to describe the plant in a certain way to get an answer? Or do I just need to start memorizing plant descriptions from books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just ordered "Botany in a Day" by Elpel - it seems to be one of the more highly recommended books to do what it seems you want to do.

This question immediately made me think of Richard Feynman and [his observation about knowing something's name](https://medium.com/@samirnazim/the-difference-between-knowing-the-name-of-something-and-knowing-something-2d14f14089c8) and understanding it:

> "See that bird? It’s a brown-throated thrush, but in Germany it’s
> called a halzenfugel, and in Chinese they call it a chung ling and
> even if you know all those names for it, you still know nothing about
> the bird. You only know something about people; what they call the
> bird. Now that thrush sings, and teaches its young to fly, and flies
> so many miles away during the summer across the country, and nobody
> knows how it finds its way."

Good luck on your search. Please update if you find a good one.

Update: I've also got an app for my phone that has been very useful called "iNaturalist". It takes your photo of a plant, attempts to classify it, and submits the picture for others to evaluate. I've been able to get several identifications with it, and its initial guesses are usually enough to get you close. I don't recall if its geared to my part of the world or not.

The book is heavily weighted on identification through the flowers of plants, so if you don't have that, it is less useful.

Comment: This looks like it might be what I want. Any update on whether it has been helpful for you? I completely understand Feynman's point, but I would say that knowing a thing's name also gives you the key to start understanding it by being able to do research.

Comment: I find that it is indeed helpful, but not necessarily what I was looking for. I was looking for something that would be along the lines of "botany in a nutshell", while this book is focused on making identifications. Nothing wrong with that, but it's a different approach. It is a valuable book to have. As for Feynman's point, he does state that it is valuable to name things in order to communicate with others, but if YOU want to understand the thing, knowing the name is not sufficient. I do agree that knowing where to start reading about something is important!

Answer (score 2):

When I studied horticulture I had to learn ten plants per week. Scientific name, common name, name of the family, and identifying it. I recommend learning the names of plants relevant to you - local plants, local weeds, plants you find interesting. Then name the plants as you pass by them.

Answer (score 1):

The Royal Horticultural Society has more than one Encyclopedia you can buy; the one I have is Gardeners' Encyclopedia of Plants and Flowers which lists over 8,000 plants;  there is a section with images of many of them. They have quite a few publications available on various subjects, e.g., there's one on Trees, Leaves, Flowers and Seeds, described as a 'visual encyclopedia of the plant kingdom', so it depends what suits your needs best. Even so, none of these will allow you to input details of a plant you've seen, for obvious reasons, for that you would need a Plant App of some sort. There are other publications covering food plants like vegetables, these are usually separate books, as are wild plants, and I have a collection or library of separate books on these things,as well as a Herb book, a Tree ID book and so on.

I will confess to reading my Encyclopedia from cover to cover years ago when I first became interested in gardening (I knew nothing of plants all those years ago). It took me a while, but I found it very interesting  and helpful - after that, I signed up for Horticultural College, but I still use both the Encyclopedias I have at times, despite the advent of the internet because increasingly, some plant info on the internet is inaccurate, so I often just cross check in the books.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I'll definitely look into what the Royal Horticultural Society has available. I've recently picked up a couple of books for vegetables since I'm trying to start a garden.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this site vPlants.org  (http://vplants.org/portal/plants/glossary/plate_all.php) some years ago and have a printed out copy of the plates which I use to help identify plants. There a ton of links to reference docs and search feature that I haven't personally used, but looks useful.

The plates help me to exactly describe the plant I'm looking at and by adding some additional details like colors of flowers, location and time of bloom I can usually find a good starting point to figuring out what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very compact information in the link and good suggestions for using it to help in researching. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Get a guidebook to the plants in your region. This will help narrow it down when trying to look up a particular plant. For example, Newcomb's Wildflower Guide is a standard field reference for wildflowers, flowering shrubs and vines of Northeastern and North-Central North America.

Any decent plant guide will have a summary of basic plant parts and characteristics. Read that section. It will teach you the basic anatomy of a plant, how to describe a plant, and what parts of the plant to look at. It should also teach you how to look up a plant in that particular guidebook.

Characteristics that you should look for when trying to identify a plant include:

- Is the leaf compound or simple?
- Are the leaf margins smooth/entire, toothed/serrate/dentate, lobed, etc?
- How are the leaves arranged relative to each other? Is there one leaf attached at each node, or more than one?
- Are parts of the plant hairy? Which part(s)?
- Are the leaf veins parallel or branching?

Then go outside and look for wild-growing plants to identify using your new guidebook. Make your best attempt at identifying a plant, looking for all the specific characteristics necessary to work your way through the key in your guidebook. Don't get discouraged at this stage; keying out your first few plants using a guidebook is absolutely the most challenging part of learning plant ID. Once you have made a reasonable guess at identifying a plant, take several pictures of it, being sure to capture the parts of the plant necessary for identification. At a minimum that means a good photo of one or more leaves, an overall plant that shows its general shape and structure, and a close-up of any flowers or fruit that are present. Post your photos to an app like iNaturalist, and see if other people agree with your identification. If someone suggests a different ID, use your guidebook to look up the species they suggest. Look at the description of that plant, and compare it to your plant.

Once you know what kind of plant it is, look for other specimens of the same plant. The more you can confidently identify individuals of that species, the better you will get at telling different plants apart from each other.